# Android - NoClassDefFoundError on Added API Class

Tags: android, jar, noclassdeffounderror

I am currently testing the Android API and its database classes. To do this, I created an application and test that calls up these database classes (especially SQLiteDatabase). The test and application run fine normally, but to get coverage, I decided to go in and add a "cov" class to the `android.database` package in the Android API that would collect coverage from modified versions of the android.database and android.database.sqlite classes. I imported "android.database.cov" into my class, and the test itself runs fine, but when I get to using cov

```
System.out.println(cov.printArray());
cov.reset();
```

I get the following failure trace on my JUnit test:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.database.cov
at com.example.sql2.test.SQLSuiteVer2.testSuite(SQLSuiteVer2.java:91)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:192)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1584)
```

Does anyone know what this is happening? I'm assuming we missed something in creating our android.jar file, or some initialization for the "cov" class.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the class defined? `public class cov {...}` Also, please read about [Java naming convention](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm) which suggests classes start with a capital letter like `Cov` or `Coverage`.

Comment: In cov.java. I have compressed it into the android.jar file with the other API classes.

Comment: "I have compressed it into the android.jar file with the other API classes." The jar file will be updated automatically as long as cov.java is in `src/your.package.name` and has `package your.package.name`.

Comment: cov.java is meant to be in the package with the Android API, however. It interacts with all of them to collect coverage (cov provides the variable that collects it, and almost all of the android.database(.sqlite) classes reference/add to that variable.